# Swift parse JSON formatting

Tags: ios, json, swift

I created an API that has a JSON response in the following format:

```
[{"name":"xxx","direct_link":"http:\/\/domain.com\/images\/xxx.png","image":"http:\/\/domain.com\/images\/xxx.png"},{"name":"yyy","direct_link":"http:\/\/domain.com\/images\/yyy.png","image":"http:\/\/domain.com\/images\/yyy.png"}]
```

Notice how the JSON response has no array title.

My Swift code looks like this:

```
       do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
            teamJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


            //getting the JSON array teams from the response
            let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["teams"] as! NSArray


            //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
            for i in 0 ..< teams.count{

                //getting the data at each index
                let teamId:Int = teams[i]["name"] as! String!
                let teamName:String = teams[i]["direct_link"] as! String!
                let teamMember:Int = teams[i]["image"] as! Int!

                //displaying the data
                print("name -> ", teamId)
                print("direct_link -> ", teamName)
                print("image -> ", teamMember)
                print("===================")
                print("")

            }
```

Notice how the array is looking for a title "teams". How can I ensure the JSON is properly parsed and displays the 3 values I need for the JSON response? I'm new to app coding and have a web background, still trying to wrap my head around this.

As it stands when I try to build and run I get the following error: `fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Comment: What do you mean by `How can I ensure the JSON is properly parsed`?

Comment: Alex I should have been more clear. When I build and run the app I get the following error: `fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Comment: You should read about the Swift Language Guide. It covers optionals in great detail

Comment: `let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["teams"] as! NSArray`

This is the part that is not playing well with my JSON response, my JSON response does not contain "teams".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: `let teamId:Int = teams[i]["name"] as! String!` wut

Comment: Thsnk you for the link, I will definetly be doing a lot of reading in the coming days. The String! should be Int! - typo on my end when posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
do {
    guard let teams = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray else {
        //Doesn't exist, or isn't an NSArray
        return
    }

    for team in teams {
        //getting the data at each index
        let teamId = team["name"] as! String
        let teamName = team["direct_link"] as! String
        let teamMember = team["image"] as! Int

        //displaying the data
        print("name -> ", teamId)
        print("direct_link -> ", teamName)
        print("image -> ", teamMember)
        print("===================")
        print()
    }
}
//...
```

Some notes:

1. Don't cast to implicitly unwrapped optionals (e.g. `String!`)
2. Don't add unnecessary type annotations
3. Use `guard let` to enforce preconditions (e.g. the `JSON` isn't nil, and is castable to `NSArray`).
4. Prefer iterating over elements of an Array (`for team in teams`) over iterating a range (`for i in 0..<teams.count`)

   - If you need only the indices, use `for i in teams.indices`
   - If you need the indices and elements, use `for (index, team) in teams.enumerate()`

Comment: Thank yu Alex, i tried the snipped but I'm getting the following error `'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'NSARRAY'; did you mean to use...`

Comment: Whoops, `as` should be `as?`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That was it, I also had to change Image to string as it wasnt a number. Thank you for both the link earlier for me to read and the snipped so I can work/break/learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
teamJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

because you are trying to cast a JSON array to a dictionary.

Just use

```
teamJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

And then you also won't need to do this:

```
//getting the JSON array teams from the response
let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["teams"] as! NSArray
```

Because teamJSON is already the array.

I think the key issue you have to be aware of is that `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` can return either an NSDictionary OR an NSArray, depending on whether the root level data in the JSON is an array or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:**

Your `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` would return an `NSArray` and not `NSDictionary`

SOLUTION:

Update code as below:

```
var teamJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray

//getting the JSON array teams from the response

let teams: NSArray = teamJSON
```

**ALSO**

**Don't force cast values using** `!`

Always cast it as optional using `?`